# Laravel - How to create distance between card and pagination

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image]

I write the "Post Two" using bootstrap 4 and the page numbering using pagination but why card and pagination glued together in bootstrap 4. i want to make a blank distance between the card and pagination, I can move it to center or right side i can separate them using `<hr>`. but still can't separate them with blank space. This is the index file of Posts page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    @if (count($posts) > 0)
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <div class="card bg-light card-body mt-2">
                <h3><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3>
                <small>Written on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        {{$posts->links()}}
    @else
        <p>No Posts Found</p>
    @endif
@endsection
```

and this is the PostsController page

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('title','desc')->paginate(1);
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Bootstrap related, nothing to do with Laravel/Eloquent. You can either change

```
<div class="card bg-light card-body mt-2">
```

to

```
<div class="card bg-light card-body my-2">
```

But that would leave you with "margin-4" between your cards. Best way would be to wrap your pagination in a `<div>`:

Change

```
{{$posts->links()}}
```

to

```
<div class="mt-2">
  {{$posts->links()}}
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: thanks its working now although the limit is `mt-5`, is there any way to have bigger than that?

Comment: Glad it works. If you're using Sass "_You can add more sizes by adding entries to the $spacers Sass map variable._" Or create your own spacer in plain CSS